# Particle System OnTriggerEnter not working (but all other functions does)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have simple script, onTriggerEnter2d when enemy hit player = minus 1 life etc. works perfect.

now I want to add particle system explosion to it and nothing is happening. not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Player have BoxColider2d with trigger ticked.

Thanks for any help.

some code:

ENEMY:

```
 public ParticleSystem explosion;
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D enter)
 {
 if (enter.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
 {
     HartCount.HartValue -= 1;
     gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
     Destroy(this.gameObject);
 }
 }
```

I tried also this:

```
 public GameObject explosion;
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D enter)
 {
 if (enter.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
 {
     HartCount.HartValue -= 1;
     Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, Quaterion.identity);
     Destroy(this.gameObject);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Do the particles have colliders? Is collision between the player layer and particle layer activated?

Comment: Do either of these objects have a rigidbody2d?

Comment: Chillersanim - Particle have collider, and Layers I have set as default and it seems like supposed to work.

Eddge - Enemy and Player have rigidbody2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have not put a particle system as a child of the gameobject, try this:

```
public GameObject explosion;  //drag the particle system prefab here
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D enter)
{
   if (enter.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player")) //when the enemy collides with the Player
   {
      HartCount.HartValue -= 1;
      GameObject particle = Instantiate (explosion, this.transform.position, Quaterion.identity);
      particle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
      Destroy(this.gameObject);
   }
}
```

Make sure the particle system is scaled up enough so that it is actually visible.
The code above will spawn a particle system of your choice (the one you have dragged into the "explosion" field in the editor) at the position of the enemy.

Answer (score 1):

So after some digging, I found the likely cause for your problem.
Particle systems don't trigger OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter events.
Instead they trigger a custom event namely [OnParticleCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnParticleCollision.html).

In essence, this method can get called on the particle system object, as well as on the object that was hit.
You could use it like this:

```
public ParticleSystem explosion;

private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
{
    if (other.tag.Equals("Player"))
    {
        HartCount.HartValue -= 1;
        gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Be aware that this is an adapted copy of your code.
There is actually another problem with it:
You play the particle system, but then you destroy the gameObject directly after, thus the particle system also disapears.

**Note 1:**
The documentation is lacking clear information about how to retrieve more information about a particle collision.
The example code in the linked page uses something like this:

```
var collisionEvents = new List<ParticleCollisionEvent>();
myParticles.GetCollisionEvents(other, collisionEvents);
```

Where myParticles is a reference to your particle system.

However, there is no documentation on this method.
Instead there is some documentation on the obsolete static [GetCollisionEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticlePhysicsExtensions.GetCollisionEvents.html)
I guess the documentation is outdated, thus you should go with the non-static method.

**Note 2:**
I'm not sure why the Enemy is able to hit your player, based on the documentation, that shouldn't happen.
But maybe I just missinterpreted something.